# tensorflow session.run() hangs while attempting to restore rnn model based on tutorial code

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I've been walking through the RNN code in TenserFlow tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

The original RNN code is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

I saved the trained RNN model as 'train-model' through

```
if FLAGS.save_path:
    print("Saving model to %s." % FLAGS.save_path)
    sv.saver.save(session, FLAGS.save_path, global_step=sv.global_step)
```

Now I'm trying to restore the saved model and run additional test with it by

```
with tf.name_scope("Test"):
    test_input = PTBInput(config=eval_config, data=test_data, name="TestInput")
    with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
        mtest = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=eval_config,
                     input_=test_input)

save = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as session:
    save.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./"))
    test_perplexity = run_epoch(session, mtest)
```

It seem that the model is loaded correctly, but it hangs at the line

```
    vals = session.run(fetches, feed_dict)
```

in function `run_epoch`, when called for computing `test_perplexity`.  `CTRL-C` is unable to quit the program, and the GPU utilization is at 0%, so it is most probably blocked on something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you run this part in pdb?  control+c there should give you more info.  just after the save.restore() line, add:

import pdb
pdb.set_trace()

at the console, execute the run_epoch()

Comment: Check if the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406697/tensorflow-running-training-op-hangs-forever) solves your problem; it did mine, although my problem was a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Tensorflow from source. It is recommended because you can build the desired Tensorflow binary for the specific architecture (GPU, CUDA, cuDNN).

This is even mentioned as one of the Best Practices for improving Tensorflow performance. Check the  [Tensorflow performance  Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide). A small excerpt from the same :

> Building from source with compiler optimizations for the target hardware and ensuring the latest CUDA platform and cuDNN libraries are installed results in the highest performing installs.

The problem you mentioned typically occurs when the configured Compute Capability with which the Tensorflow binary was built is different than that of your GPU. But installing it from source gives you an option to configure the specific Compute Capability. Check the [guide for installing from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources).